# Showing a continuous function is bounded on $[0,\infty)$ given a limit at $\infty$

Tags: calculus

let $f$ be continuous on the interval $ [0, \infty)$ so that:$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=L$$

How can I prove based on this that $f$ is bounded on the given interval?

Comment: @ClementC. My bad I meant bounded

Comment: Hint: $f$ is bounded on any set of the form $[0,M]$.

Comment: @DavidMitra But my interval is open

Comment: In particular, choose $M$ such that $|f(x)|<L+1$ when $x\ge M$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Can I choose $M=\infty$? cause i just dont get it logically :(

Comment: No. Choose $M$ as stated above. From the limit condition, there *is* an $M$ so that $f$ is bounded on $[M,\infty)$ (it's bounded by $L+1$, say). Now $f$ is bounded on $[0,M]$, by $A$, say. On the entire interval, $f$ will be bounded by the bigger of $A$ and $L+1$. Drawing a picture may help here...

Answer (score 2):

Using the convergence, choose $M>0$ large enough that for $x > M$, $|f(x)| \leq |L|+1$. (This amounts to choosing $\varepsilon=1$ in the definition.) Then $f$ is bounded on $(M,\infty)$. $f$ is bounded on $[0,M]$ because $[0,M]$ is compact and $f$ is continuous. So $f$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$ by the maximum of the other two bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is to prove uniform continuity.By definition $\exists G>0$ such that $\forall x>G,|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ and $f(x)$ being continuous on compact set $[0,G]$ is uniformly continuous there and hence bounded

Comment: Haven't learned about the uniformly continuous definition, How did you conclude that:
"By definition $\exists G>0$ such that $\forall x>G,|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$"

Comment: You don't really need uniform continuity, you just need to know that a continuous function on a compact set is bounded, which is easily proven directly. If it isn't bounded, then find $x_i$ so that $|f(x_i)|>i$. Since the domain is compact, $\{x_i\}$ must have a convergent subsequence, etc.